# SFDX force:source:deploy with -x parameter not deploying all components in package.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, issue

I've just encountered a very troublesome issue using sfdx with the `-x` parameter to deploy components using only the ones listed in `package.xml`

I have a one big sfdx project folder where I retrieve all my sprints related components in `force-app` folder. Every time I get a new sprint, I only create a new `package_sprint_number.xml` for that sprint and retrieve them. And for deployment I don't deploy complete `force-app` folder I use a specific `package.xml` and deploy that using the following command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u ORG_alias -x manifest\package_sprint_number.xml --verbose >> DeployLog.txt
```

But all of a sudden sfdx has started acting strange and is missing components at random from the mentioned package.xml during deployment without any errros, warning and messages.

I am forced to move to deploying using the following command which deploys the complete force-app folder. Now I have to create a new `force-app` folder for every new list of components I get for the time being. But managing that is a pain.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u ORG_alias -p force-app --verbose >> DeployLog.txt
```

As you can clearly see deploying complete  force-app folder is not feasible. For example If I retrieve just 5 new custom objects using a new package.xml to my project. I won't be able to deploy just those components.

Anyone else faced this ? Any workaround to achieve my desired workflow ?

Comment: Hi, this is happening to me as well, did you find the solution?